# A bounded sequence satisfying $2a_n \le a_{n+1} +a_{n-1}$ for all n converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Question: Let $(a_n)$ be a bounded real sequence such that $2a_n \le a_{n+1} +a_{n-1}$ for all positive integers n. Let $b_n = a_{n+1} - a_n$.

Show that $(b_n)$ converges to 0 and that $(a_n)$ converges.

I have shown that $(b_n)$ is a monotone increasing sequence that is bounded above and so it must converge. However, I am struggling to show that $(b_n)$ converges to 0. I have tried using the fact that $b_{n} +b_{n-1}$ = $a_{n+1} - a_{n-1}$ but I really don't think this is getting me anywhere. I would appreciate some hints as to how to actually show $(b_n)$ converges to 0 as well as how to prove that, as a consequence, $(a_n)$ converges.

Comment: One way to geometrically think about this is to picture a concave function (that's what $a_n\leq \frac{a_{n+1}+a_{n-1}}2$ means). If you want that function to be bounded, then its slope has to be flat at infinity and the function itself has to tend to a finite limit.  Otherwise, your function is either greater or smaller than a linear function at towards infinity.  See @Kavi Rama Murthy's answer below for the formal proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $b_n \to b$. If $b >0$  then $a_{n+1}-a_n \to b$ and $a_{n+m}-a_m=b_{n+m}+b_{n+m-1}+...b_{m+1}>(b-\epsilon)+(b-\epsilon)+...+(b-\epsilon)$ ($m$ terms) if $m$ is sufficienlty large. This makes $(a_n)$ unbounded, so $b$ cannot be $>0$. A similar argument shows $b$ cannot be $<0$ so $b=0$.

Now $b_n$ is increasing to $0$ so $b_n \leq 0$ for all $n$. This makes $a_n$ decreasing. It is also bounded, hence convergent.

Comment: Wow that's a very nice argument. Thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is wrong, but if someone could correct me, I'd appreciate it.

We have,
$2a_n - a_{n-1} \leq a_{n+1}$ which shows that if $a_{n} > a_{n-1}$ then $a_{n+1} \geq 2a_{n}-a_{n-1} > a_n$.
Since $a_n$ is bounded, it converges to some real valued limit $a$.

Given $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a positive integer $N$ such that whenever $n \geq N$, $|a_n - a| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$.
By the triangle inequality, $|b_n| = |a_{n+1} - a_{n}| \leq |a_{n+1} - a| + |a - a_n| < \varepsilon$. So $b_n$ converges to 0 as desired.